# Error using gets because it is dangerous?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the `gets' function is dangerous? Why should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-is-dangerous-why-should-not-be-used)

Just started a tutorial in socket programming. But I got this error after compiling with gcc. How to overcome this gets dangerous?

```
In function `main':
tcpserver.c:(.text+0x1f3): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

This line of code was obtained from internet (http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/07/socket-programming-tutorial.html):

```
printf("\n  Your message (hit q or Q to quit): ");
              gets(send_data);
```

Comment: See [Why is the `gets' function is dangerous? Why should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-is-dangerous-why-should-not-be-used)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gets()` blindly writes data into the buffer you give it.  It neither knows nor cares about the length of the buffer, making it a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) waiting to happen.  If you can, use `fgets()` instead.

For (slightly) more on the dangers of gets, see [the Linux gets/fgets manpage](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/gets.3.html).

Comment: POSIX's [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is also a good alternative

Comment: @paxdiablo: Why did you change "`Gets`" to "It"? It seems a minor grammatical point at best.

Comment: It was just incongruous - in languages where case matters, I have a hard time capitalising function names since a newbie may see that as authorising `Gets (buff);` for example, clearly an error. I usually write things like "The function `gets`" or (as in this case where there's only one subject, "It". Change it back if you disagree, it is your answer after all :-) I just thought it was better this way.

Comment: You make good points, and I was just wondering anyway --- can't get angry enough to change it back, and too lazy anyway :P.  I picked up my style in the book I learned Unix from, where sentences would start with "`Tar` format is by far the most popular format for software distribution..."  Now that I think of it, I've never seen that style anywhere else...

Answer (score 0):

This is [a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-is-dangerous-why-should-not-be-used) of a question asked previously on stackoverflow.  Basically, gets() can be vulnerable to buffer overruns, so the compiler is suggesting you replace it with another method where you explicitly specify the maximum buffer length to read.  This sort of warning is increasingly common in compilers to encourage folks to write code that is more secure (buffer overruns are a common source of security vulnerabilities).

Your tutorial code was presumably written before this guidance became common practice.